# "опробовать" vs "попробовать"

Tags: словоупотребление, значения

Context: They're talking about some newly developed equipment.

> **Опробуй** их разок, а?

The speaker used "опробовать", but how does "попробовать" compare?

> **Попробуй** их разок, а?

Given that the prefix "о-" imparts the meaning of "to the full extent", does  "опробовать" express the idea of "testing/experimenting with something thoroughly"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `опробовать` means something like `try out`, `make a test of` or `make an experiment with` some **new** equipment, solution, approach.
Also `опробовать` relates to a noun:

> Опробовать *noun*.

Examples:

> Опробовать оборудование / решение / подход.

---

`Попробовать` has a wider meaning: `try`, `try out`, `taste of` almost everything.
Typically used as:

> Попробовать [*verb*] *noun*.

Examples:

> Попробовать [*съесть*] мясо.
>   Попробовать [*использовать*] другую отвертку.

And a verb is very often omitted.

Also it may be used to express a threat:

> Только попробуй [*do smth*]!

Comment: "Опробовать другую отвертку" means "Try out the different, new screwdriver". "Попробовать другую отвертку" means "Try a different screwdriver for your task" (or "Try to take a bite off a screwdriver" :) ).